# What is the best algorithm to detect leading edge?

Tags: signal-analysis, signal-detection

I am interested to detect leading edge of one dimensional signal. There may be several algorithm for edge detection, specially for image processing (2 dimensional), but my interest is on one dimensional signal. I am specifically looking for algorithm which can reject trailing edge.  Any suggestion or useful link to an algorithm?

Comment: Not knowing the real "answer ", my first hunch is a simple differentiator (difference) with a threshold detection and ignore any negative answers (ignore falling edges). Noise is reduced at the expense of precision by increasing the span between samples in which to take the difference.